# Is it possible to share encoded video across gstreamer pipelines using shared memory?

Tags: gstreamer, video-capture

I'm looking to create a short-lived gstreamer pipeline to consume an encoded video stream generated by another, separate long-lived pipeline.

The intent is to connect to the primary pipeline periodically, grab some video and save it to a file.

I'm trying to implement this using shared memory sinks (`shmsink`) and sources (`shmsrc`). My pipelines currently look like this (simplified for clarity):

```bash
# Primary (producer)
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
videotestsrc ! 'video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1' \
! videoconvert \
! x265enc ! 'video/x-h265,profile=main' \
! h265parse \
! shmsink socket-path=/tmp/foo shm-size=2000000 wait-for-connection=false sync=true

# Secondary (consumer)
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
shmsrc socket-path=/tmp/foo do-timestamp=true is-live=true \
! 'video/x-h265,profile=main,width=1280,height=1080,framerate=30/1' \
! h265parse \
! mp4mux \
! filesink location=output.mp4
```

Both of these run without error but output.mp4 is always zero-bytes.

Is there something wrong with either of these pipelines? Is the idea of sharing h265 encoded video with shared memory flawed?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get a playable output by simply tweaking your producer command to:

```bash
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
videotestsrc do-timestamp=true is-live=true \
! 'video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1' \
! videoconvert \
! x265enc ! 'video/x-h265,profile=main' \
! h265parse \
! shmsink socket-path=/tmp/foo shm-size=2000000 wait-for-connection=false sync=true
```

Notice that `do-timestamp=true` and `is-live=true` were missing so my guess is that it is required to include those options if the consumer command also has them.

Extra checks:

- ffprobe seems to looks healthy
- mediainfo also looks reasonable:

```
General
Complete name                            : output.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                                 : mp42 (mp42/mp41/isom/iso2)
File size                                : 4.07 MiB
Duration                                 : 5 min 38 s
Overall bit rate                         : 101 kb/s
Frame rate                               : 1.464 FPS
Encoded date                             : 2023-05-12 10:34:55 UTC
Tagged date                              : 2023-05-12 10:40:41 UTC

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : HEVC
Format/Info                              : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile                           : Main@L4@Main
Codec ID                                 : hvc1
Codec ID/Info                            : High Efficiency Video Coding
Duration                                 : 5 min 38 s
Bit rate                                 : 101 kb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 5 456 kb/s
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Original width                           : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.185
Original display aspect ratio            : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 1.464 FPS
Minimum frame rate                       : 0.399 FPS
Maximum frame rate                       : 30.000 FPS
Original frame rate                      : 30.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.050
Stream size                              : 4.07 MiB (100%)
Encoded date                             : 2023-05-12 10:34:55 UTC
Tagged date                              : 2023-05-12 10:40:41 UTC
Codec configuration box                  : hvcC
```

Answer (score 1):

There is just one issue into the pipelines.

1. Make sure you define H265Parse element with `config-interval=-1` property value. By default [config-interval](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/videoparsersbad/h265parse.html?gi-language=c#h265parse:config-interval) would be zero, but you would want it to be other than zero to get this special config frame with encoding parameters.

After this change the pipelines look like this:

```bash
# Primary (producer)
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
videotestsrc ! 'video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1' \
! videoconvert \
! x265enc ! 'video/x-h265,profile=main' \
! h265parse config-interval=-1 \
! shmsink socket-path=/tmp/foo shm-size=2000000 wait-for-connection=false sync=true

# Secondary (consumer)
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
shmsrc socket-path=/tmp/foo do-timestamp=true is-live=true \
! 'video/x-h265,profile=main,width=1280,height=1080,framerate=30/1' \
! h265parse config-interval=-1 \
! mp4mux \
! filesink location=output.mp4
```

Comment: That is interesting thank you. Are you able to explain more about what config/params are included in the stream actually are? The docs mention VPS, SPS and PPS